# How to read a txt file in rails and save after showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application in Ruby on Rails and I need to read a certain TXT file that will be sent by the user, after sending the file, the data of the file will be displayed to the user so that it confirms if the file is correct, and if yes, in Then save it, the file contains letters that are the answers of a test and each letter represents an issue, for example:

"EEDEBACABDBBADAADEADEAB"

That is, "1 => E, 2 => E, 3 => D, 4 => E"

but every letter must be in a different column as dislplayed down

```
id | question | answer
1      1          E
2      2          E
1      3          D
```

This file will be sent in .txt format through a form, I hope it has been better understood

thoughts?

Comment: I'm unclear on the connection between that string of letters and the other thing you're describing. Can you edit your question and give a more concrete example? Where do these `id` values come from? Why aren't the answers grouped together into some sort of result-type record?

Comment: Sure, doing that!

Comment: I have an application in Ruby on Rails and I need to read a certain TXT file that will be sent by the user, after sending the file, the data of the file will be displayed to the user so that it confirms if the file is correct, and if yes, in Then save it, the file contains letters that are the answers of a test and each letter represents an issue, for example:

"EEDEBACABDBBADAADEADEAB"

That is, "1 => E, 2 => E, 3 => D, 4 => E"

This file will be sent in .txt format through a form, I hope it has been better understood

Comment: Questions column i assume is in a series, answer is answer, what is id? N where do u get it from?

Comment: id, in this case is just the auto_increment field

Comment: Don't explain what it's doing in a comment. Instead, clarify the original question by rewriting it to be more understandable. Using comments forces us to read every comment to figure out what you are really asking. Just edit the question and edit it. Don't add "edit" or "update" tags as we can tell what changed and when if we need to know.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you really want to do is expand the text file into records like this:

```
File.read(params[:file].path).chomp.chars.each_with_index do |answer, i|
  Answer.create(question: i, answer: answer)
end
```

Where `params[:file]` is the file uploaded under the name "file", and Answer is the model into which these are inserted.

Normally in Rails you'd have a relationship structure like:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answer_sets
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, through: :answer_sets
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers
end

class AnswerSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer_set
  belongs_to :quiz
end
```

Where this allows for multiple quizzes, each with multiple questions, and then a series of answer sets each of which contains multiple answers.

Comment: Almost, it, but first, I need to display the result in the page and then, if the user authorizes, he saves the result

Comment: You might want to just save them anyway but with some "authorized" flag not yet set. If they approve, flip the flag. If not, purge the record later on. Stringing this data along from one request to the next without saving it is messy.